# Regular expression for validating length

Tags: regex, string, go

I am writing a function to perform a simple regex-based pattern matching in Go, and need to additionally validate the length of the string that I would like to match against the pattern. 
Here is the requirements for my regex:

- The first character must be alphabetic or numeric
- The last character must be alphabetic or numeric
- Any characters between first and last must be alphabetic, numeric, or any of '.', '_', and '-'
- The minimum length is one character
- The maximum length is 255 characters

```
func validateUserEnvironmentName(name string) bool {
    var validEnvName = regexp.MustCompile(`^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,255}$`)
    return validEnvName.MatchString(name)
}
```

The regex is able to validate every use case other than the case when the input exceeds 255 characters. Does regex in Go provide a mechanism to validate the length of the entire pattern or should I modify the regex to accommodate this particular use case?

Here is the Go Playground link to test against - https://play.golang.org/p/GmGYh8vtx34

Comment: Go with `^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][\w.-]{0,253})?[a-zA-Z0-9]$`

Comment: You can always test the length of a string by adding a positive lookahead at the beginning of the regex: `(?=.{10,20}$)`. In languages like Perl and Ruby, where `$` denotes the end of a line (rather than the end of the string) you may need to substitute `\z` fo `$`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Lookarounds are not supported in RE2 regex engine.

Comment: @Wiktor, ah. That would be a challenge. Do you know if there are plans to add them?

Comment: Currently the minimum length of your own regex is 2. But you mentioned it should be 1. So not only it exceeds the max length but also it exceeds the min length. Yet my first comment satisfies your rules.

Comment: @CarySwoveland From what I know, there no such plans.

Comment: @revo, consider posting your suggestion as an answer, perhaps with the easy mod if in fact the minimum length is one.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regular expression for that. Just check the length of the string normally. Regular expressions are slow and computationally-expensive, so should only be used when they're really needed.